# ThreadPoolExecutor not fully executing threads before shutting down

Tags: java, multithreading

When I run this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Foo {

    static public ExecutorService pool =
            new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                    50, 200, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(),
                    ExLogThread.factory);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            pool.execute(Foo::startApp);
            pool.shutdown();
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            for (StackTraceElement elem : ex.getStackTrace())
                System.out.println(elem);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    static void startApp() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}

final class ExLogThread extends Thread {

    public static final ThreadFactory factory =
            ExLogThreadFactory.instance;
    private final StackTraceElement[] predecessor;
    private final Runnable r;

    public ExLogThread(Runnable r) {
        super();
        predecessor = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            r.run();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log(ex, predecessor);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    private static class ExLogThreadFactory
            implements ThreadFactory {

        static public ExLogThreadFactory instance =
                new ExLogThreadFactory();

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            return new ExLogThread(r);
        }

        private ExLogThreadFactory() {}

    }

    private static void log(Exception ex, StackTraceElement[] predecessor) {
        // for example's sake
        for (StackTraceElement elem : ex.getStackTrace())
            System.out.println(elem);
        for (int i = 1; i < predecessor.length; i++)
            System.out.println(predecessor[i]);
    }

}
```

It's exiting with a code of 0. What's going on? I thought ThreadPoolExexcutor waits for the queued tasks to run before shut down. If so, this should exit with a code of -1.

If I don't delegate the creation of threads to a factory creating subclasses of thread, I get informed of an error before the main thread exits with a code of 0.

I'm guessing I got something wrong with creating a subclass of Thread, but I don't know where. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `pool#awaitTermination` after calling `pool#shutdown`

From [shutdown's javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown()):

> This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete
>   execution. Use awaitTermination to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `System.exit(0)` will terminate the running `ExecutorService`.

The call to `shutdown()` is non-blocking; it simply signals the executor service that no more tasks will be submitted, so resources can be cleaned up as the tasks that were already submitted complete. Because it doesn't block, `System.exit(0)` is called immediately, aborting the submitted tasks.

If you want a thread to wait until all tasks submitted to the `ExecutorService` have completed, call [`awaitTermination()`,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) indicating how long you are willing to wait.